# Numbering LaTeX bibliography with APA-like formatting

Tags: styles, latex, biblatex

How can I number a LaTeX bibliography with APA-like formatting?

I have tried

```latex
\bibliographystyle[numbers]{apalike} 
\bibliography{arqrefbib}
```

but this does not render numbers in the bibliography.

Answer (score 1):

There's a package called `apa6` on CTAN. See http://www.ctan.org/pkg/apa6.

The page reads:

> The class for­mats doc­u­ments in APA style (6th Edi­tion). It pro­vides a full set of fa­cil­i­ties in three dif­fer­ent out­put modes (jour­nal-like ap­pear­ance, dou­ble-spaced manuscript, LATEX-like doc­u­ment), in con­trast to the ear­lier apa6e, which only for­mats dou­ble-spaced manuscripts in APA style. The class can mask au­thor iden­tity for copies for use in masked peer re­view.